# Feather read failure from pandas with pd.cut data

Tags: python, pandas, feather

The following read-write sequence through feather throws with error:

`ArrowInvalid: Ran out of field metadata, likely malformed`

```py
dg = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.cut((1, 2, 3), bins=[0, 1, 2])})
file_name = 'myfile.feather'
dg.to_feather(file_name)
dg=pd.read_feather(file_name)
```

(it's surprising to me that the `to_feather` step doesn't complain).

I checked that the following works fine, which suggests it's not just a categorical variable limitation - must be something related to the type returned by `pd.cut`.

```py
dg = pd.DataFrame({"A": list("123321")}, dtype="category")
file_name = 'myfile.feather'
dg.to_feather(file_name)
dg=pd.read_feather(file_name)
```

I really want to not lose the categorical meta-data resulting from my cut as I persist the df through feather. Any recommendations?

I am using pandas 1.5.3, pyarrow 11.0.0 and python 3.8.13 on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it works for your solution. You have to replace `(` with `[` and convert it into string.

```
dg = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.cut(range(1, 2, 3), bins=[0, 1, 2])})
print(dg['A'][0]) 
# replace ( with [ and convert it into string
dg['A'] = dg['A'].astype(str).str.replace('(', '[', regex=True)
print(dg['A'][0]) 
file_name = 'myfile.feather'
dg.to_feather(file_name)
dg = pd.read_feather(file_name)
dg
```

Comment: What exactly is that magic about? is that basically converting the values to string? I tried it and end up with: 
`Name: A, dtype: object` so I have lost the categorical nature of the data in the process

Answer (score 0):

I figured out two things:

- it seems to be a tracked bug (unresolved as of this post):
  https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/20196
- a somewhat decent (preserves the ordering etc.) workaround is to pass the `labels=` argument to `pd.cut`. So I came up with this wrapper for automatically setting labels:

```
 def my_cut(series, bins):
    return pd.cut(series, bins=bins, labels=[i for i in range(len(bins)-1)])
```

usage (fairly transparent):

```
dg = pd.DataFrame({'A': my_cut((1, 2, 3), bins=[0, 1, 2])})
```